# How to remove attribute from item in DynamoDB table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-sdk-java

I have an item whose particular attribute I want to remove using SDK 2.x from DynamoDB. How do I do this? I am using enhanced DynamoDB for table management. Here's a code sample:

```
DynamoDbTable<T> mappedTable = AwsConfig.getTableSchema(schema, clazz);
T updatedRecord = mappedTable.updateItem(request -> {
                request.ignoreNulls(true);
                request.item(record);
});
```

I would appreciate a solution using enhanced DynamoDB client.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by remove attribute, if you refer to not have an attribute persisted in dynamoDB you can use `@DynamoDbIgnore`

```
@DynamoDbBean
public class SomeDynamoDBEntity {

    @DynamoDbIgnore
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable value to `null` in your `record` class object. And do not set `ignoreNulls` to `true`.  EnhancedClient will remove that respective attribute from the item with UpdateItemEnhancedRequest.

Ref: read `ignoreNulls` in documentation [here](https://javadoc.io/static/software.amazon.awssdk/dynamodb-enhanced/2.16.13/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/model/UpdateItemEnhancedRequest.Builder.html)